# SUDS Exception Imported Schema Failed

Tags: python, soap, tcp, suds

I'm getting the error:

> Exception: imported schema (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema) at
>   (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.x sd), failed

when passing a Doctor (constructed with *ImportDoctor*) to the **suds** *Client* constructor.

I'm working on two *Windows* machines, both of them got the same version of **suds** installed, but only one of them rises the error above.

Could someone guide me here to know why this error rises?, so I can figure out what's missing on the machine where it happens?.

Thanks in advance!!!.

**UPDATE**: I don't really know if this is important, but it's worth noting that my *Windows* machine that is rising the error is an *Amazon Web Services* instance. At my local machine everything's working well!.

**UPDATE**: Here's some code I ran at the python interpreter of the machine I mentioned. Here you can detail how the error is rising...

```
>>> from suds.client import Client
>>> from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor, Import
>>> missing_import = Import("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
>>> missing_import.filter.add("http://tempuri.org/")
>>> doctor = ImportDoctor(missing_import)
>>> client = Client("http://etcfulfill.ebooks.com/Fulfillment.asmx?wsdl")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "suds\client.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File "suds\reader.py", line 152, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File "suds\wsdl.py", line 159, in __init__
    self.build_schema()
  File "suds\wsdl.py", line 220, in build_schema
    self.schema = container.load(self.options)
  File "suds\xsd\schema.py", line 95, in load
    child.dereference()
  File "suds\xsd\schema.py", line 323, in dereference
    midx, deps = x.dependencies()
  File "suds\xsd\sxbasic.py", line 422, in dependencies
    raise TypeNotFound(self.ref)
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(schema, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )'
>>> client = Client("http://etcfulfill.ebooks.com/Fulfillment.asmx?wsdl", doctor=doctor)
No handlers could be found for logger "suds.xsd.sxbasic"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "suds\client.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File "suds\reader.py", line 152, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File "suds\wsdl.py", line 159, in __init__
    self.build_schema()
  File "suds\wsdl.py", line 220, in build_schema
    self.schema = container.load(self.options)
  File "suds\xsd\schema.py", line 93, in load
    child.open_imports(options)
  File "suds\xsd\schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "suds\xsd\sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "suds\xsd\sxbasic.py", line 567, in download
    raise Exception(msg)
Exception: imported schema (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema) at (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd), failed
```

**UPDATE**:

I realized that **suds** connections always open in *TCP* increasing ports, and if it reaches the maximum *TCP* port (65535) then it starts opening again from the minimum *TCP* port available, so there's no problem with this.

The problem shows up when using **suds** *ImportDoctor*, because it has to open a previous connection to the location where the import should be retrieved, and for some reason, if the system reaches the maximum *TCP* port count, then **suds** somehow assumes that there's no *TCP* port available to open the connection for obtaining the import, and in consecuence it throws the exception:

> Exception: imported schema (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema) at (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd), failed

I repeat, this only happens if **suds** has to open this previous connection for obtaining the import. If *ImportDoctor* is not used, then **suds** has no problem if the *TCP* port count reaches its maximum, it just restarts at the minimum port available.

Does anyone has any clue on how to resolve this issue???. I'd really appreciate the help!!!.

Comment: Does this also happen when using suds-jurko: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-jurko/0.6? suds is no longer maintained.

Comment: I'm actually using the original suds library. Changing to suds-jurko is not in my scope right now, but suds has been working pretty well, I only got this weird issue!!!. Thanks anyway!!!

Comment: I had to use `Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/', location='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'); doctor = ImportDoctor(imp)` to make it work.

Comment: I've tried what you said. Not working for me yet!!!. I'm guessing it could be something regarding networking cause as I described it in the question, it is failing in a AWS machine, and it works sometimes but then fails again!!!. Confusing!!!. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It could also be a problem with the service you're using. If they have a misconfigured website that's sometimes serving incorrect (or no) WSDL file then you can get this. Or it could be a network problem on your end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what the problem was. The schema that was missing from the *WSDL* I was trying to use with **suds** was:

> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

And the *XSD* file for this schema is at:

> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd

So when I used **suds** *ImportDoctor* to add this schema import, sometimes the *w3.org* domain was denying my access (don't know why really) and that's why this error was rising:

> Exception: imported schema (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema) at (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd), failed

What did I do to solve this problem?. I just downloaded this schema to my machine and used **suds** *ImportDoctor* to retrieve this import locally.

And that was it!!!. Confusing bug!!!. But **SOLVED**.

Comment: could you please show us how did you load the schema locally? thanks

Comment: I no longer have access to this code. But it should only be a matter of importing with ImportDoctor from a local URL. When using missing_import = Import("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"), try a local URL to the downloaded XSD file instead of going through HTTP to the hosted file by w3.org. Hope this helps!.

Comment: @john was you able to import a local url? i tried
imp = Import('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', location='file://XMLSchema.xsd')
imp = Import('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', location='XMLSchema.xsd')
but no one works.